# Can a CTAN package install both document class and accompanying LyX layout?

Tags: lyx-layouts, ctan

I'm writing a document class which is supposed to come with a LyX layout. I'd want to distribute them both as a single unit, for example, as a CTAN package. Is this barely possible?

Comment: I have a document class at CTAN. In my case, I put some ancillary materials in a zip file, in the docs folder. Images, shell scripts, HTML. No problem. You don't necessarily have to zip it. The `mwe` package (by someone else) has images in the tex folder, where they can be found and used by other packages. Now, I don't know how LyX layouts work, but you can always ask the user to copy your layout file from where it is located, out to the user's document working directory. In other words, the layout is not directly installed into LyX by the distro, you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I do not know the CTAN policies, the common procedure from the LyX project's perspective is to post the layout file [here](https://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Layouts). After some testing, it is possible that the layout file would be shipped with LyX, and any modifications or updates you would want to make for the layout file would be welcome.

In my opinion, the main advantage of including a layout file in the package on CTAN would be if the TeX distributions took care of installing the layout file. Below is some speculation on why that is not likely to happen:

I've never thought about it before, but I can see why you would want to include it in the CTAN package. It makes sense to keep everything together, rather than split them apart in different methods of distribution. Your question is just about CTAN, but I thought a related and interesting question to ask is "if the layout file were permissible to put on CTAN, could the TeX distributions take care of installing it to make using it as seamless as possible for the users?" Here are my thoughts on that question:

1. I do not think TeX distributions want to take care of installing the layout file in the correct directory, and then subsequently running a LyX reconfigure (the LyX analog of texhash) so that LyX recognizes the layout file is there.
2. A LyX layout file has a file format, and thus each layout file requires a minimum version of LyX. A TeX distribution would have to take care of making sure that the LyX version is high enough for the layout file, or there will be confusion. It's not clear what the behavior should be if the user's version of LyX is not high enough (perhaps no installation the layout file and a warning to the user?).

TeX distributions already have a very difficult job to do, and I'm confident that they do not want to add extra complication because of LyX.